# ctypes in Python 2.6 help

Tags: python, ctypes

I can't seem to get this code to work, I was under the impression I was doing this correctly.

```
from ctypes import *


kernel32 = windll.kernel32

string1 = "test"
string2 = "test2"

kernel32.MessageBox(None,
                       string1,
                       string2,
                       MB_OK)
```

** I tried to change it to MessageBoxA as suggested below **
** Error I get :: **

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 366, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "C:\Python26\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 371, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: function 'MessageBoxA' not found
```

Answer (score 4):

MessageBox is defined in user32 not kernel32, you also haven't defined MB_OK
so use this instead

```
windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, string1, string2, 1)
```

Also I recommend using [python win32 API](http://python.net/crew/mhammond/win32/Downloads.html) isntead of it ,as it has all constant and named functions

edit: I mean use this

```
from ctypes import *

kernel32 = windll.kernel32

string1 = "test"
string2 = "test2"

#kernel32.MessageBox(None, string1, string2, MB_OK)
windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, string1, string2, 1)
```

same thing you can do using win32 api as

```
import win32gui
win32gui.MessageBox(0, "a", "b", 1)
```

Comment: I meant you are using wrong dll, see i have put whole code again with changed line

Comment: Oh I was talking about the win32 api think, I didn't realize it was a link :pp

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the function you're trying to call isn't actually named `MessageBox()`.  There are two functions, named `MessageBoxA()` and `MessageBoxW()`: the former takes 8-bit ANSI strings, and the latter takes 16-bit Unicode (wide-character) strings.  In C, the preprocessor symbol `MessageBox` is `#define`d to be either `MessageBoxA` or `MessageBoxW`, depending on whether or not Unicode is enabled (specifically, if the symbol `_UNICODE` is defined).

Secondly, according to the [`MessageBox()` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505(VS.85).aspx), `MessageBoxA/W` are located in `user32.dll`, not `kernel32.dll`.

Try this (I can't verify it, since I'm not in front of a Windows box at the moment):

```
user32 = windll.user32
user32.MessageBoxA(None, string1, string2, MB_OK)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh and anytime you are confused about if a call needs kernel32 or user32 or something of the sorts. Don't be afraid to look for the call on MSDN. They have an [Alphabetical List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383688(VS.85).aspx) and also a list based on [categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383686(VS.85).aspx).
Hope you find them helpful .