# Python message box shows only the first letter of my title and my message

Tags: python, messagebox, rhino3d

I have a simple script in Python which I run in Rhino3D.
It shows a message box as following :

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, "Your text", "Test", 1)
```

Moreover, it shows only the first letter of each of my text (title and content).
How can I solve it ? What is the reason ? Is the problem coming from Rhino3D ?

[image: Python Message Box]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String problems with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14648448/string-problems-with-python)

Comment: I tried running your code and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: Also use MessageBoxW  rather than MessageBoxA

Comment: As @Destrif pointed, you can use `MessageBoxW(0, u'Hello', u'Window title', 0)`

Comment: @Destrif yes it works well. Danke Schon.

Comment: Please remove the `rhino` tag on this question, because this question is related to rhino3d, not rhino

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The solution for your code is :

```
import ctypes  # An included library with Python install.
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, b"Your text", b"Test", 1)
```

Strings should be byte, so use `b''`.
And I think this problem only appears in Python3.